# Django button click gets triggered but not updating model

Tags: django, button, time

I tried to upload the image several times, for some reason it just won't upload. I will explain in detail -

This table is on my django template.It will display data from a model called "WorkOut". This page has a form above this table for manual data input. Three fields in the table are going to be dynamic, that is where the issue is. In the picture you will see the "Start Time" field that says none. I want to fill this field with a button click. Idea is to click the button, that will trigger a views.py function and that will update the model and then display on this page. Once I do this successfully I will add the end time and do some calculations after.

I added a small form in the for loop to generate the button-

```html
<td>
            <form method="get">
            <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Start Time" name="start_time">
            </form>
        </td>
```

Here is the views function that it is suppose to trigger-

```html
def index_2(request):
     
    if(request.GET.get('start_time')):
        time=datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S')
        WorkOut.objects.update(start=time)


    products=WorkOut.objects.all()
    context={'products': products}
    return render(request, 'myapp/index.html', context)
```

This page is the index and no separate url for the button click. I don't think I need one.

Here is the main index views:

```html
def index(request):
    form = WorkOutForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = WorkOutForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            
   products=WorkOut.objects.all()
   
   context = {'form': form, 'products': products }

   return render(request, 'myapp/index.html', context)
```

When I click the button it seems to get triggered but the function is not doing what it is suppose to do. My localhost url changes from 127.0.0.1:8000 to http://127.0.0.1:8000/?start_time=Start+Time. So something is happening but not the desired action.

Any idea what need to be changed?

Thank you for any input.

Comment: For some reason the image didn't upload after multiple attempt. But the I described the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

submit button value does not submit, so add a hidden field

index view:

```
def index(request):
    form = WorkOutForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = WorkOutForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    elif request.GET.get('start_time'):
        time=datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S')
        WorkOut.objects.update(start=time)
            
   products=WorkOut.objects.all()
   
   context = {'form': form, 'products': products }

   return render(request, 'myapp/index.html', context)
```

form

```
<td>
        <form method="get">
            <input type="hidden" value="1" name="start_time">
            <input type="submit" class="btn">
        </form>
</td>
```

Comment: It didn't work. The only thing that changed is the url up top. It looks like this now- http://127.0.0.1:8000/?start_time=1

Comment: Can any other field be an issue like the model? I am using CharField to take the value in which I think should be ok. Here is how the actual model field looks like - start=models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)

Comment: when you click submit button, request reaches index view (not index 2) so change view (updated answer) or you can set action attribute of the form (first way is good)

Comment: Thank you . That almost worked. Only issue, single button click populating all the field. Definitely a pk issue. I tried to add that in the def index(request, pk): and in else statement like this : elif request.GET.get('start_time', id=pk): , but no luck. Tried to add a url with pk. It just keep throwing the error "index() missing 1 required positional argument: 'pk'" . Thank you for your help so far though. I appreciate it.

Comment: you can send pk in another hidden form field, get request.GET.get('pk') after checked start_time. if your problem is solved, don't forget to upvote and mark as solved the answer!

Comment: Well it didn't completely solved the problem but I appreciate your input. You definitely helped me with the first step. I will try  a couple of things and see if I can make it work. Thank You.